# (OAuthException) (#2201) response does not match challenge

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, response

Please help, I'm becoming desperate. I'm trying to subscribe for real time user updates. Doing everything the right way, I assume, but every time I get this error

(OAuthException) (#2201) response does not match challenge, expected value = 'SOME-NUMBER', received='

When I try to call callback_url with parameters sent from Facebook, from url bar in browser, I get correct response, but from code I always get the same error.

Code part is this:

result = fb.Post(string.Format("/{0}/subscriptions", this.FacebookSettings.ApplicationID), new Dictionary { { "object","user"}, { "fields","status" }, { "callback_url", "http://www.mysite.com/locationOfAshxFile/" }, { "verify_token", "myVerifyToken" }});

Maybe I should mention that, even if my verify token is not correct, I still get the same error, but when I try to call subscription method from localhost, i curl error, with correct callback url and GET data, but curl error is ok I guess.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You may have solved this problem on your own... I just had this same problem. I solved it by outputting the verify token in the callback page.

See the call back source example https://github.com/facebook/real-time/blob/master/samples/php/callback.php